# Mover body junto com menu lateral

Tags: php, html5, css3

Estou criando um código, onde o mesmo possui um menu lateral que ao passar o mouse por cima desse menu ele expande para o lado.

Porém o problema que estou enfrentado é que quando o menu se expande para o lado, ele está cobrindo uma parte do conteúdo da página.

Semelhante às imagens abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria deixar o código dinâmico, que no momento que o usuário passasse o mouse por cima do menu, ele se expanda, porém o body se mova junto com o menu para o lado.

Segue abaixo o código que estou usando.

**CSS**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*, html, body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* regra para o clear float */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {content: " ";display: table;}
.cf:after {clear: both;}
.cf {*zoom: 1;}
body {
  margin-left:55px; /*espaço à esquerda para a barra vertical vísivel do menu */
 font:  62.5%/1.2 Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  #lateral {
 padding:0 50px 0 0;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
 font-size:1.2em;
 background:rgb(44,62,80);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79));
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79));
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79) );
       background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79));
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79));
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:370px; 
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:-320px;
 }

#lateral:hover:before, #lateral:focus:before {
left:-500px
 }
#lateral:hover, #lateral:focus,  #lateral:active  {
 overflow-y:scroll;
 -moz-transform: translate(320px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(320px, 0);
   -o-transform: translate(320px, 0);
    transform: translate(320px, 0);
 padding-right:0;
  }
  


#menu {
 font-style:italic;
 position:relative;
 font-size:1.0em;
 margin:1em 0 1em -1em;
 padding:0;
 }
#menu  {padding:0; margin:0;}

#menu  a:hover {
 color:rgb(255, 0, 0);
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
body {margin-left:0;background-size:100% 28em!important;}
#lateral {
 padding:0;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
 font-size:1.2em;
 height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
 width:100%; 
 position:static;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 }
#lateral:before {
 z-index:1000;
 width:0;
 text-align:center;
 content: "";
 font-size:0;
 color:white;
 position:static;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:inline-block; 
 }
#lateral:hover, #lateral:focus {
 overflow:scroll;
 -moz-transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none;
   -o-transform:none;
    transform:none;
 }
}
.cor{
  background-color:white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 15px;
}
a{
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">

    </head>

    <body>

     
            <div id="lateral">
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul class="collapsible popout">
                        <li>
                          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Entrada</div>
                          <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="cliente.php"> Cadastro </a></div>
                          <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>SEGUNDO</div>
                          <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                          <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>TERCEIRO</div>
                          <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                          <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>

                
                
                </div> <!-- /#menu -->
                
                </div> <!-- /#lateral -->
      <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>   
                  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
      </script>


    </body>
  </html>
```

Cliente.php ( tela com a Tabela )

```html
<?php
include_once 'home.html';
include_once 'conexao.php';
?>



<body>
<Button class='cor' onclick="window.location='cadastrocliente.php'"> Novo Cliente </button>

<table border="" class="display" width="50%">
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th>NOME</th>
  <th>TELEFONE</th>
  <th>Ação</th>
</tr>
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_cliente";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($res){
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $linha['NOME_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['TELEFONE_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['ID_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    
    <?php
}
}
?>
</thead>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com jQuery, use os eventos `mouseenter` e `mouseleave` para alterar a margem esquerda do body (`margin-left`) usando `.animate()` quando o mouse passar sobre a `div#lateral`.

Como você está usando um breakpoint de 500 pixels pra baixo para converter o menu em modo mobile, coloque a animação dentro de um `if` condicionando-a a rodar somente se a largura da tela for maior que 500px.

```js
$(function(){
   $("#lateral").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e){
      if(window.innerWidth > 500){
         $("body").stop().animate({
            "margin-left": (e.type == "mouseenter" ? 375 : 55) + "px"
         });
      }
   });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

*, html, body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* regra para o clear float */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {content: " ";display: table;}
.cf:after {clear: both;}
.cf {*zoom: 1;}
body {
  margin-left:55px; /*espaço à esquerda para a barra vertical vísivel do menu */
 font:  62.5%/1.2 Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  #lateral {
 padding:0 50px 0 0;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
 font-size:1.2em;
 background:rgb(44,62,80);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79));
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79));
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79) );
       background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79));
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3,8,12), rgb(16,57,79));
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:370px; 
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:-320px;
 }

#lateral:hover:before, #lateral:focus:before {
left:-500px
 }
#lateral:hover, #lateral:focus,  #lateral:active  {
 overflow-y:scroll;
 -moz-transform: translate(320px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(320px, 0);
   -o-transform: translate(320px, 0);
    transform: translate(320px, 0);
 padding-right:0;
  }
  


#menu {
 font-style:italic;
 position:relative;
 font-size:1.0em;
 margin:1em 0 1em -1em;
 padding:0;
 }
#menu  {padding:0; margin:0;}

#menu  a:hover {
 color:rgb(255, 0, 0);
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
body {margin-left:0;background-size:100% 28em!important;}
#lateral {
 padding:0;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
 font-size:1.2em;
 height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
 width:100%; 
 position:static;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 }
#lateral:before {
 z-index:1000;
 width:0;
 text-align:center;
 content: "";
 font-size:0;
 color:white;
 position:static;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:inline-block; 
 }
#lateral:hover, #lateral:focus {
 overflow:scroll;
 -moz-transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none;
   -o-transform:none;
    transform:none;
 }
}
.cor{
  background-color:white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 15px;
}
a{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lateral">
 <div id="menu">
     <ul class="collapsible popout">
         <li>
           <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Entrada</div>
           <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="cliente.php"> Cadastro </a></div>
           <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div> 
         </li>
         <li>
           <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>SEGUNDO</div>
           <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
           <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
         </li>
         <li>
           <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>TERCEIRO</div>
           <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
           <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
         </li>
       </ul>

 
 
 </div> <!-- /#menu -->
 
 </div> <!-- /#lateral -->
<button class='cor' onclick="window.location='cadastrocliente.php'"> Novo Cliente </button>

<table border="" class="display" width="50%">
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th>NOME</th>
  <th>TELEFONE</th>
  <th>Ação</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $linha['NOME_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['TELEFONE_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $linha['ID_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz uma classe chamada `.ativa`, e coloquei um `transition` na `div` com o conteúdo que chamei de `div .contudo`. Assim quando vc faz um `mouseenter()` na div do menu eu adiciono essa classe .ativa no na `div conteudo` e quando vc faz o `mouseleave()` eu retiro essa classe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

**OBS:** Esse erro no console é por causa do seu script não do meu :D

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    @charset "UTF-8";

    *,
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* regra para o clear float */
    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }

    .cf:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .cf {
        *zoom: 1;
    }

    body {
        margin-left: 55px;
        /*espaço à esquerda para a barra vertical vísivel do menu */
        font: 62.5%/1.2 Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #lateral {
        padding: 0 50px 0 0;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background: rgb(44, 62, 80);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 370px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: -320px;
    }

    #lateral:hover:before,
    #lateral:focus:before {
        left: -500px
    }

    #lateral:hover,
    #lateral:focus,
    #lateral:active {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -moz-transform: translate(320px, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate(320px, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(320px, 0);
        transform: translate(320px, 0);
        padding-right: 0;
    }



    #menu {
        font-style: italic;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1.0em;
        margin: 1em 0 1em -1em;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #menu {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #menu a:hover {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        body {
            margin-left: 0;
            background-size: 100% 28em !important;
        }

        #lateral {
            padding: 0;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 100%;
            position: static;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        #lateral:before {
            z-index: 1000;
            width: 0;
            text-align: center;
            content: "";
            font-size: 0;
            color: white;
            position: static;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #lateral:hover,
        #lateral:focus {
            overflow: scroll;
            -moz-transform: none;
            -webkit-transform: none;
            -o-transform: none;
            transform: none;
        }
    }

    .cor {
        background-color: white;
        font-weight: bolder;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    a {
        display: block;
    }
    .conteudo {
        transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
    }
    .ativa {
        margin-left: 320px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>



    <div id="lateral">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="collapsible popout">
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Entrada</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="cliente.php"> Cadastro </a></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>SEGUNDO</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>TERCEIRO</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                </li>
            </ul>



        </div> <!-- /#menu -->

    </div> <!-- /#lateral -->

    <div class="conteudo">
        <button class='cor' onclick="window.location='cadastrocliente.php'"> Novo Cliente </button>

        <table border="" class="display" width="50%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NOME</th>
                    <th>TELEFONE</th>
                    <th>Ação</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_cliente";
                $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                if($res){
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    ?> -->
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['NOME_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['TELEFONE_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['ID_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <!-- <?php
                }
                }
                ?> -->
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
            var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, options);
        });

        // Or with jQuery

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.collapsible').collapsible();
        });

        $("#lateral").mouseenter(function(event){
            $('.conteudo').addClass("ativa");
        });
        $("#lateral").mouseleave(function(event){
            $('.conteudo').removeClass("ativa");
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

---

**Apenas com CSS**

Se vc quiser fazer apenas com CSS, sem precisar de JS ou jQuery vc pode apenas fazer uma regra assim:

```
.conteudo {
    margin-left: 0;
    transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
}
#lateral:hover + .conteudo {
    margin-left: 320px;
}
```

Segue o código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    @charset "UTF-8";

    *,
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    /* regra para o clear float */
    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }

    .cf:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    .cf {
        *zoom: 1;
    }

    body {
        margin-left: 55px;
        /*espaço à esquerda para a barra vertical vísivel do menu */
        font: 62.5%/1.2 Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #lateral {
        padding: 0 50px 0 0;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        background: rgb(44, 62, 80);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(3, 8, 12), rgb(16, 57, 79));
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 370px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: -320px;
    }

    #lateral:hover:before,
    #lateral:focus:before {
        left: -500px
    }

    #lateral:hover,
    #lateral:focus,
    #lateral:active {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -moz-transform: translate(320px, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate(320px, 0);
        -o-transform: translate(320px, 0);
        transform: translate(320px, 0);
        padding-right: 0;
    }



    #menu {
        font-style: italic;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1.0em;
        margin: 1em 0 1em -1em;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #menu {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #menu a:hover {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        body {
            margin-left: 0;
            background-size: 100% 28em !important;
        }

        #lateral {
            padding: 0;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 100%;
            position: static;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        #lateral:before {
            z-index: 1000;
            width: 0;
            text-align: center;
            content: "";
            font-size: 0;
            color: white;
            position: static;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #lateral:hover,
        #lateral:focus {
            overflow: scroll;
            -moz-transform: none;
            -webkit-transform: none;
            -o-transform: none;
            transform: none;
        }
    }

    .cor {
        background-color: white;
        font-weight: bolder;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    a {
        display: block;
    }
    .conteudo {
        margin-left: 0;
        transition: margin-left 0.5s ease;
     
    }
    #lateral:hover + .conteudo {
        margin-left: 320px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>



    <div id="lateral">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="collapsible popout">
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Entrada</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="cliente.php"> Cadastro </a></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>SEGUNDO</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>TERCEIRO</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body cor"><a href="#">TESTE</a></div>
                </li>
            </ul>



        </div> <!-- /#menu -->

    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <button class='cor' onclick="window.location='cadastrocliente.php'"> Novo Cliente </button>

        <table border="" class="display" width="50%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NOME</th>
                    <th>TELEFONE</th>
                    <th>Ação</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_cliente";
                $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                if($res){
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    ?> -->
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['NOME_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['TELEFONE_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $linha['ID_CLIENTE']; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <!-- <?php
                }
                }
                ?> -->
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
            var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, options);
        });

        // Or with jQuery

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.collapsible').collapsible();
        });


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```